# How to solve ValueError in isin pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to check if the values in a pandas column contains a particular values.When I did
rc=536510  1c6069a82417,536538  15e20b94cfde...
rc is a dataframe containing some building_id

```
if((train['building_id'].isin(rc))):
    train['building_id'].apply('Strong')
else:
    train['building_id'].apply('week')
```

It shows this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can anyone say how to do this.

Comment: Where is your [mcve] and reproducible data sample?

Comment: train['building_id'].isin(rc).any()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. Here random id's are created using `hashlib.md5()`. The code checks if values in the `train['building_id']` are present in `rc['rc_id']`.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
# Create sample dataframe - 1

rc= pd.DataFrame({'rc_id': abs(np.floor(np.random.randn(20)*1e4))})
rc['rc_id'] = rc.apply(lambda x: hashlib.md5(str(x['rc_id']).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)
rc.head()

# Create sample dataframe - 2

rc2 = pd.DataFrame({'rc_id': abs(np.floor(np.random.randn(20)*1e4))})
rc2['rc_id'] = rc.apply(lambda x: hashlib.md5(str(x['rc_id']).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)
rc2.head()

# Create dataframe train

train = rc.sample(n=10)
train = train.append(rc2.sample(n=10))
train.columns = ['building_id']
train = train.sample(frac=1)
train.head(2)
```

**Using `where()` clause to check for a match**

```
train['is_in_rc'] = np.where(train['building_id'].isin(rc['rc_id']), 'yes', 'no')
train
```

[image]